# ng-pattern for the same password and confirm password

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```js
app.directive("pwCheck", function () {
    alert('hey');
       return {
           require: 'ngModel',
           link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
               var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck;
               elem.add(firstPassword).on('keyup', function () {
                   scope.$apply(function () {
                       // console.info(elem.val() === $(firstPassword).val());
                       ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', elem.val() === $(firstPassword).val());
                   });
               });
           }
       }
   });
```

I have a signup form and users must to input a password and a confirm password, My problem is my directive is not working in validating the password in confirm password to check if the password are the same, Is there another way to implement this validation like ng-pattern to check if the inputs are the same?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your directives?

Comment: I updated my post see my directives. Actually it is working in my previous system. My problem is to implement this code in an existing system given to me. So I decided to ask if there is another way to validate not using directives.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is to the `$validators` pipeline. However, this is also implemented in a form of a directive. This feature was introduced in Angular 1.3. The old fashion way was to use `$parsers` and / or `$formatters`. The huge advantage of the validators pipeline is that you have access to both, viewValue and modelValue. Just pass the password to the directive and add a new validator.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', TestController);

function TestController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.password = '';
  vm.confirmPassword = '';
}

app.directive('confirmPassword', ConfirmPassword);

function ConfirmPassword() {

  var linkFn = function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$validators.confirmPassword = function(modelValue) {
      return modelValue == scope.password;
    };

    scope.$watch("password", function() {
      ngModel.$validate();
    });
  };

  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
      password: "=confirmPassword"
    },
    link: linkFn
  };
};
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.error {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl as testCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" ng-model="testCtrl.password" type="password" />
    <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" ng-model="testCtrl.confirmPassword" data-confirm-password="testCtrl.password" type="password" />
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.confirmPassword.$invalid && !myForm.confirmPassword.$pristine">Passwords do not match!</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

This will check if both passwords are matching. If the passwords do not match the validity will be false. In this case I display an error message.